# History of provably total functions of a theory

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, ho.history-overview, reference-request

*Provably total functions* of an arithmetical theory is one of the tools used in proof theoretic analysis of theories.

I am looking for early history of its development. In particular,

> Where was the first uses of this concept?
>   Who coined the term "provably total functions"?

Answer (score 2):

One of the references I would recommend is P. Odifreddi's Classical Recursion Theory Volume II. On Page 324-326, it contains many references about the development of provably total functions (if you are seeking for the development within the Peano Arithmetic).

Comment: Thanks. I will have look but AFAIR it does talk about the development of this one.